# Cosmo DB stored procedure- call back issue in for loop

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Am trying to fetch data in a loop(for). I have reports, feedback and evidences in my DB.Input is list of reports and output will be the report details,list of feedback associated to report and list of evidences to report.

```
Sample input :- array of report id [id1,id2,id3]
sample output :-  array
                  {
                    id1:"reportid",
                    reportdetail:"reportdetails",
                    evidences :[e1,
                                e2,
                                . .
                               ]
                      feedback :[f1,f2,f3..]    
                  }

 reportArray.forEach(function(singleReport) {
this part of code is not executing because report array is coming empty always.calling this after for loops ends but because of callbacks the value is still not persist here.

    });



    enter code here
     // Get Existing Reports Stored Procedure
function sproc_GetReportsForQueue_Copy(reportObject) {

    reportObject = [{
            state: "AvailableForT1",
            reportId: '295398e7-f468-a541-9d12-70dff0809da3',
            id: 20055
        },
        {
            state: "AvailableForT1",
            reportId: '00e4a1dc-0b4e-7465-901a-5eaebd50fb41',
            id: 20055
        }
    ]
    if (!reportObject || !reportObject.length) {
        throw "Input parameters are not supplied.";
    }
    //Initialization
    var  collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var  response = getContext().getResponse();
    var reportArray = [];
    var mainArray = new Array();
    var feedbackArray = new Array();
    var evidenceArray = new Array();


    for (var i = 0; i < reportObject.length; i++) {
        //Gets the state and report id   
        var state = reportObject[i].state;
        var reportId = reportObject[i].reportId;
        var reportQuery = "SELECT r.id as reportId,r.routingTargetType as routingTargetType,r.createdTimestamp AS createdTimeStamp from r WHERE r.docType='Report' AND r.id ='" + reportId + "' AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.reportState,{state: '" + state + "',isCurrent:true},true)";
        var evidenceQuery = "SELECT e.reportId as reportId,e.id As evidenceid,{ moderatorId: e.moderatorNotes.moderatorId, comment: e.moderatorNotes.comment,timeStamp:e.moderatorNotes.timestamp } AS comments,udf.GetEvidenceInfo(e.evidenceDetails) AS evidenceDetail FROM e WHERE e.docType='Evidence' AND e.reportId ='" + reportId + "'";
        var feedbackQuery = "SELECT f.reportId as reportId,f.targetGamertag,f.textReason from f WHERE f.reportId ='" + reportId + "' and f.docType='Feedback'";

        //Gets the report         

        var isReportExists = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), reportQuery,
            function(err, documents, options) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if  (!documents || !documents.length) {

                }
                if (documents.length > 0) {
                    reportArray.push(documents);

                }
            }

        );
        if (!isReportExists) {
            throw "Unable to fetch the reports from the DB";

        }

        //Gets the Evidence
        var isGetEvidence = collection.queryDocuments(
            collection.getSelfLink(), evidenceQuery,
            function(err, Evidences, options) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if  (!Evidences || !Evidences.length) {

                } else {
                    evidenceArray.push(Evidences);

                }



            }
        );
        if (!isGetEvidence) {


        }
        var isGetFeedback = collection.queryDocuments(
            collection.getSelfLink(), feedbackQuery,
            function(err, Feedbacks, options) {

                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                if  (!Feedbacks || !Feedbacks.length) {} else {
                    feedbackArray.push({
                        Feedback: Feedbacks
                    });

                }


            }
        );
    }

    reportArray.forEach(function(singleReport) {


    });




    response.setBody();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your sql query slightly and tidied up your Stored Procedure.You could try it.

```
function sample() {

    var reportObject = [{
            state: "AvailableForT1",
            reportId: '1',
            id: 20055
        },
        {
            state: "AvailableForT1",
            reportId: '2',
            id: 20055
        }
    ]
    if (!reportObject || !reportObject.length) {
        throw "Input parameters are not supplied.";
    }
    //Initialization
    var  collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var  collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var  response = getContext().getResponse();
    var reportArray = [];
    var mainArray = new Array();
    var feedbackArray = new Array();
    var evidenceArray = new Array();


    for (var i = 0; i < reportObject.length; i++) {
        var reportId = reportObject[i].reportId;
        getReportInfo(reportId,reportArray)
        response.setBody(reportArray);       
    }

    function getReportInfo(reportId,reportArray){
        var reportQuery = "SELECT r.id as reportId from r WHERE r.docType='Report' AND r.id ='" + reportId + "'";
        var evidenceQuery = "SELECT e.reportId as reportId,e.evidenceId As evidenceid,e.evidenceDetails AS evidenceDetail FROM e WHERE e.docType='Evidence' AND e.reportId ='" + reportId + "'";
        var feedbackQuery = "SELECT f.reportId as reportId,f.textReason from f WHERE f.reportId ='" + reportId + "' and f.docType='Feedback'";

        //Gets the report
        var isReportExists = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), reportQuery,
            function(err, documents, options) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if  (!documents || !documents.length) {

                }
                if (documents.length > 0) {
                    for(var i = 0; i<documents.length;i++){
                        console.log(documents[i].reportId);
                        var map = {};
                        map["id"] = documents[i].reportId;
                        map["reportDetails"] = documents.reportDetails;
                        getEvidenceInfo(map,evidenceQuery);
                        getFeedbackInfo(map,feedbackQuery);
                        reportArray.push(map);
                    }                   

                }
            }

        );
        if (!isReportExists) {
            throw "Unable to fetch the reports from the DB";
        }
    }

    function getEvidenceInfo(map,evidenceQuery){
        //Gets the Evidence
        var isGetEvidence = collection.queryDocuments(
            collection.getSelfLink(), evidenceQuery,
            function(err, Evidences, options) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if  (!Evidences || !Evidences.length) {

                } else {
                    map["evidences"] = Evidences;
                    //evidenceArray.push(Evidences);

                }
            }
        );
        if (!isGetEvidence) {
            throw "Unable to fetch the evidence from the DB";
        }
    }

    function getFeedbackInfo(map,feedbackQuery){
        var isGetFeedback = collection.queryDocuments(
            collection.getSelfLink(), feedbackQuery,
            function(err, Feedbacks, options) {

                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                if  (!Feedbacks || !Feedbacks.length) {} else {
                    map["Feedback"] = Feedbacks;
                    // feedbackArray.push({
                    //     Feedback: Feedbacks
                    // });
                }
            }
        );
        if (!isGetFeedback) {
            throw "Unable to fetch the feedback from the DB";
        }
    }       
}
```

My output results:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks.I will try it and reply on this, Was out because of medical emergency,

Comment: jay - Any help on the this scenario would be great.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931103/cosmo-changefeed-errors-exceptions-and-service-fail-scenarios

Comment: @prabhatranjan ok.I'll check it.