# Cosmo ChangeFeed -Errors,exceptions and Service fail scenario's

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

All,

I am using Change Feed Processor Library.Want to know the best way to handle service failure along with the exceptions/errors scenario's in ProcessChangesAsync method. Below are the events am referring to.

1) Service failure - Service having the processor library crashed in the middle of some operation. How to start the process from the same document(doc on failure instance)? is there any inbuilt mechanism where change feed will start with the last failed documents?  E.g. Let assume,in current batch we have 10 docs.5 processed successfully and then service breaks because of network failure or by some other reasons.Will my process starts with 6th document once service is re-started? How to achieve this?

2) Exception and Errors- Any errors in ProcessChangesAsync method can be handle using try catch at the global level but how to persist those failure records and make them available for the next batch? Again,looking for any available inbuilt mechanism in change feed process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The Processor Library, by default, checkpoints after a successful run of `ProcessChangesAsync`. In the latest [library version](https://github.com/azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet), you can customize the Checkpointer to do manual checkpoints in case you need it. If for some reason the processor shuts down before checkpointing, then it will start processing next from the the last successful checkpoint stored in the Leases collection. In your case, it will start with the first document again, so you will never lose a change but you could experience double processing (this is an "at least once" model).

2) There is no built-in mechanism that you can leverage, handling exceptions within the `ProcessChangesAsync` is your responsibility. You could not only add a global try/catch but, in the case you are looping over the documents, add a try/catch inside the loop, to handle a failing document (maybe send it to queue for later analysis/post-process) without losing the batch. If you require logging for those errors (I'm assuming that's what you mean by persisting errors?), then the latest version is compatible with [LibLog](https://github.com/azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet#how-to-enable-tracing), so plugging your own custom logging is as simple as:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor.Logging;

var hostName = "SampleHost";
var tracelogProvider = new TraceLogProvider(); //You can use any provider supported by LibLog
using (tracelogProvider.OpenNestedContext(hostName))
{
    LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(tracelogProvider);
    // After this, create IChangeFeedProcessor instance and start/stop it.
}
```

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fkaduk/2018/08/06/logging-in-documentdb-change-feed-processor/)

**Extra info for the comments**

To avoid exceptions halting the batch or causing a batch to be reprocessed, you can have handling like this:

```
public async Task ProcessChangesAsync(IChangeFeedObserverContext context, IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        foreach(var document in documents)
        {
            try
            {
                // Do your work for the document
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Something happened with the current document, handle it, send it to a queue / another storage to analyze, log it. This catch will make the loop continue with the next.
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Something unhandled happened, log it and avoid throwing it again so the next batch is processed    
    }
}
```

Comment: @matisa - Thanks for the clarifications.  It would be great if can answer few more questions related to checkpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.It would be great if can answer few more questions related to checkpoints.1)If ProcessChangesAsync method is not throwing any exceptions(eating exceptions) then is there any chances that leaseCollection will change the continuation token and process next batch?.2) My aim here is to avoid the processing of same batch in case of errors.As mentioned,e.g.10 docs in same batch and 9 get processed successfully and 1 failed so do not want to repeat the same batch cz f failure.3)How lease work with continuation token,How it changes its value or retain the same.Thanks.

Comment: 1) Yes, if you "eat" the errors by handling them with a try/catch, see #2.
2) To do this I recommend the approach I mentioned in the answer. Add a global try/catch in ProcessChangesAsync and a try/catch in the loop. Handle each document exception accordingly so it won't halt the entire batch.
3) The Lease continuation token is updated after ProcessChangesAsync finishes with the latest processed batch's token. If ProcessChangesAsync fails, then that token will retain the previous value and the next batch will be the one that failed (generated the exception in ProcessChangesAsync)